# Creating view with user's contents

Tags: 7, views

I'd like to create view page with contents added by the user. In that page, every user can see contents only added by him. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Views UI, at the right, expand "Advanced". Simply add a relationship of User: Author and then create a filter using field User:current and make sure you use setting logged on user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using Contextual Filter in views. Do this --

- Under Advanced, add a new Contextual filter for `Content: Author uid`.
- Choose `Provide default value` and select `User ID from URL`.
- Under Page settings, set Path to **user/%/myview**.

When you navigate to **user/1/myview** now, you should see content from user 1. You can set it as page to be navigated from where ever you need.

Comment: I don't understand point Under Page settings, set Path to user/%/myview.

Comment: @user19455 You will pass UID to the views by this % as we have mentioned in filter to get UID from URL.